# viewport denoising blender 2.83 macbook pro

Tags: cycles-render-engine, osx, denoise

I'm a macbook pro user of blender 2.83

i'm trying to activate the viewport denoiser, but there is no way

anybody knows how to activate it?

my graphics are: Radeon Pro 555X 4 GB
Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB

Thank you!

Comment: No, it is not possible with your hardware.

Answer (score 1):

As written [here](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.83/Cycles)

In section about "OptiX Viewport Denoising"

> To use this feature you need a NVIDIA RTX GPU and at least driver 441.87 (Windows) or 440.59 (Linux).